# Pie Chart in QlikView - Controlling Colors

Tags: qlikview

I have a calculated dimension that yields following values: 'N', 'P', 'K'.
On top of that is an expresion. Also I am using PIE CHART to represent the data.
The numbers are calculated ok. I need help in selecting colors for the dimension values. There are predefined colors that each dimension values needs to have. How can I imprement that? In "Expression" Tab -> "Background Color" I can't reference the dimension, since it it a calculated dimension.
I appreciate the constructive feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With some chart types comes a 'Colors' tab in the chart properties window. If you go to that tab you will be presented with numerous color options for your different dimensions (calculated or not):

[image]

Change the colors to your liking and watch the Pie Chart update.

Check the 'Persistent Colors' checkbox to keep colors assigned to dimensional values.

Comment: but what will happen if my values change over time?
For example, as I mentioned, I have the following dim values 'N', 'K', 'p'. If today they have follwowing values 1,10,100 respectively, they become colors red, yellow, green. In ten days the values changes - 1,100,10. Will now 'N' become red, 'K' green, and 'P' yellow?

Comment: What I am trying to ask is - is it possible to define color in respect to dimensional value, so that no mater what the expression calculates N is red, K is yellow, P is green?

Comment: Sure, just check the 'Persistent Colors' checkbox and I think you'll get what you'll looking for.

Comment: did I understand correctly - once when the 'Persistent Colors' is checked, QV memorises to which values they are initially assigned, and remembers that even if values of the expressions in future change?

Comment: I can't tell you how helpful your posts are oGeez.
Thank you very much! :)